# How to call a singleton method?

Tags: java, reflection, singleton

I have a singleton object like:

```
Object o = new Object () {
  public void test() {
    //...
  }
};
```

But I cannot use `o.test()` because the class/interface does not have that method. Is there any way to achieve this using meta programming such as `getMethods`? Please do not suggest declaring an interface.

Comment: It may make more sense to have it be a `Runnable` instead, since you're just running a void method, right?

Comment: @phflack It is more just a sample code here... It is more complex in my real code.

Comment: In that case, you should probably go with reflection if you dislike the elegancy of interfaces in OOP

Comment: @phflack It is just a little annoying because there is only one such object and I have to create a new interface just for it

Comment: Even with only being used once, just how many methods are in it?  If there are a lot, it might make more sense to use a [local class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html) which you only ever use once, but is a bit more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By reflection:

```
o.getClass().getMethod("test", null).invoke(o, null);
```

But this is normally a very ugly thing to do.

Comment: I did this `o.getClass().getMethod("test").invoke(o);`... works and a bit simpler

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively...

```
Class cls = Class.forName(className);
Method method = cls.getMethod("test", new Class[0]);
Object o = method.invoke(null, new Object[0]);
```

Comment: It's an anonymous inner class, so `Class.forName` won't work.